# Como definir placeholder no EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Criei um pequeno app para Android contendo apenas uma activity. Nela eu coloquei dois componentes **EditText**. Desejo definir **placeholders** neles, como nos inputs do HTML5, mas não encontro solução.

Comment: android:hint="O que deseja colocar"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Descobri a solução!

No Android Studio, o componente **EditText** não possui a propriedade **placeholder**, porém existe a propriedade **android:hint**. E com isso descobri também a propriedade **android:textColorHint** que altera a cor do texto em questão.

Veja abaixo como ficou meu exemplo.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAltura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
        android:hint="Ex.: 1.82"
        android:textColorHint="#bbb"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Resultado

[image: Propriedade android:hint]

Comment: thanks my king   =)

Answer (score 3):

Vais nas propriedades da EditText e procure por Hint. Funciona como um placeholder.